# Structure emberjs application as different modular apps

Tags: ember.js

We are new to emberjs and are looking to replace our existing project client side with a SinglePage Framework like EmberJs. We have an issue with the way Ember is structured at first glance.

Our structure at the moment is like so:

- /web

  - core
  - apps

    - app1
    - app2

We would like to keep that sort of structure but looking at ember you can only have 1 app and then each up would have to spread its files in the different directories (i.e routes, controllers, models, etc)
Is there a way to have emberjs apps running next to each other and talking to each other?

Comment: I would suggest either in-repo-addons, or ember-engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the `ember-cli` default structure is highly under discussion. For example [here](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/124) you can see the current state of that. Important is also to notice the new `engines` feature [here](https://github.com/dgeb/ember-engines) and [here](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/10).

As you see this topic is currently under development but will definitely have a bright future.

You can also always override the resolver and implement something yourself if your project is big enough for that.

**EDIT:**

The current discussion moved to [here](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/143).